# How to Load Plugin JS in theme's footer section

Tags: plugin-development, javascript

I am working on optimizing my theme so that the load time can be decreased, as of now i have used `wp_enqueue_script()` to add my custom js file and everything is working fine as expected.

One thing which i am not very well aware of, the way plugin hook there js and css files.
I want to force plugin to add there java-script files on the footer section of my theme, currently they are being loaded in the header section.

Can anyone help me to understand how this can be done (if possible).

Answer (score 7):

The available input parameters of `wp_enqueue_script()` are:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>
```

where `$in_footer` is `false` by default. If you set it as `true` then the script will be placed into the footer, but you will need to have `wp_footer()` in your theme.

You should check out the Codex for more info:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

**Update:**

Here is how it's done in the plugin *JavaScript to Footer* to move all the javascript files from the header to the footer:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
```

See the plugin source:

http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/footer-javascript/trunk/footer-javascript.php

Comment: is there any way to load all scripts in the footer like `wp_enqueue_script(true)` and it should load everything in footer?

Comment: I updated the answer